# Not able to read the Kubernetes secret from a nested

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am very new to Kubernetes. My task is to move the existing application from Kubernetes to EKS. I am using CDK EKS Blueprints to create the cluster in AWS and have AWS secret manager to create the Kubernetes secret. I followed the same steps as given in here https://aws-quickstart.github.io/cdk-eks-blueprints/addons/secrets-store/
As mentioned on the above page I got the service account, a role in the service account to access the secret and the secret created.
Though I have a volume block, mount path for the secret and used env variables to refer the secret, I am not able to get my pod up and running. Instead it complains that the key is not found in the secret.

The reason may be because when I try to create a secret manually using the create command the Kubernetes create the secret as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N7WC.png)
But when the Kubernetes secret is created by EKS blueprints by lookingup the existing AWS secret like
***secretProvider: new blueprints.LookupSecretsManagerSecretByName('test-aws-secret'),***
it is creating as an encoded object.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjDmX.png)

Now I am not sure how to reference the nested object in the yaml. I tried many iterations, something like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti3Gi.png). But no luck. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `key` field should be `key1`:

```
- name: key1-value
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: secret-test
      key: key1
```

Including `data/secret-test/` before the key name is unnecessary because Kubernetes already knows the secret name from the `name` field and knows to look for keys under the `data` field of secrets.

See [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables) for more information.

Comment: When I try to refer the existing AWS secret in the AWS Secret manager using blueprints it is creating Kubernetes secrets in the encoded format as shown in the second image. So referring the secret with a key as key: key1 is not working. I am getting key not found error.